# Can Eclipse debug my Windows exe built with makefile?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, debugging, makefile

I have built a C++ exe using my own makefiles. I have Eclipse CDT. I don't want to use Eclipse to "manage" my project. Can it be used simply as a debugger? If so I need explicit instructions.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't debug projects, it uses GDB (or whichever debugger your toolchain has), it only presents the information in a GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Eclipse CDT wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn80#Project-less_debugging):

> ### Project-less debugging
>
> CDT can now be used to debug any binary, without needing to specify or even create a project in Eclipse. This is supported for all types of debugging (local, remote, attach, and post-mortem sessions).

[image]

Comment: This has my attention. I have updated my Eclipse from the web and can't get this feature to work. I don't see project-less debugging and even when my program is launched and its std output appears in eclipses console, I can't breakpoint. It complained that the exe was not a recognized format too.

Comment: Accepting with reservations. Couldn't get it to work but the information is useful and researched.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is just a front-end to GDB. You'd be better off just using GDB, but if you insist on an IDE, yes, you can point Eclipse at your makefile so that it can find your sources, and then you can tell it to debug your executable.

Comment: I want a graphical debugger but don't see how Eclipse can do it for me.

Comment: Why not? you just create a debug config that points to the program. You aren't on Windows, are you?